# MVC post form using Ajax on post back form state and JQuery reset

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I hope someone could point me in the right direction regarding Ajax post. I have a long form which has a number of questions which are toggled depending on the previous value that was selected.
When I post the form using Ajax, the form submit successfully and the `_Success` Partial displays correctly. However, if I make an error in the form and then submit. On post back all JQuery stops working the MVC `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` display correctly but the toggled fields are reset along with the green validation.

How do I keep the previous state? Or am I doing this wrong and there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Form field before submit]

[image: Form After submit toggled question now hidden and colour missing]

**My code example:**

**View**

```
<div id="test-container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialView",Model)
</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("SendReport","Report")" data-form-ajax="true" data-form-target="#test-container">


// form fields here
```

**Controller**

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // set model 
                    return PartialView("_PartialView",model);
                }

                // more model methods

                if (model.RecordMessage.Type == MessageType.Success)
                {
                    return PartialView("_Success", model);
                }
                else
                {
                    return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
                }
            }
```

**Ajax**

```
var ajaxSubmitForm = function () {


    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {


        $("#test-container").html("");
        $("#test-container").append(data);
    });

    return false;
};


$("form[data-form-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxSubmitForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-enable validation you can append back the form to the jquery validator. This should be handled after the append itself.

```
var form = $("#myForm");
form.removeData('validator');
form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

Also it might be required to reactivate those toggles if you are using some jquery plugin with them.

Comment: Thanks Cristian for your solution. I have just noticed this post and this is actually what i ended up doing too!!